# Confused about Operation and OperationQueue QoS relationship

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

The `OperationQueue` documentation states for the `qualityOfService` property:

```
This property specifies the service level applied to operation
objects added to the queue
```

However one can simply check that this is not true by just copy & pasting the code below into a new playground.

```
import Foundation

let q = OperationQueue()
q.qualityOfService = .userInitiated

print("QUEUE", q.qualityOfService.rawValue)

let op = BlockOperation()
op.addExecutionBlock {
    print("OP", op.qualityOfService.rawValue)
}

q.addOperations([op], waitUntilFinished: true)
```

You will see that the queues QoS level is `25`/`.userInitiated` and the operations `-1`/`.default`.

So does it mean that the operations QoS level is `.default` in relation to the queues elevanted `.userInitiated` level, or is it `.default`, despite the queue having a higher QoS level?

What I actually expect is that these 2 values should be the same.

PS: I need to invoke a `Process` inside the `Operation`, which in turn also has a `qualityOfService` setting that should be the same as the queue/ops.

Comment: This is weird, since documentation states for the `op.qualityOfService` property that "The default value of this property is NSQualityOfServiceBackground and you should leave that value in place whenever possible." You can check it by enabling Low Power Mode on the device - in case if the system interprets `op.qualityOfService == .background`, operation won't be executed until low power mode is disabled.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk - First, the documentation is incorrect. The operation’s default QoS is `default`, as shown in Erik’s question, not `background` as the documentation suggests. I've filed a bug report re the documentation. Second, I would advise against determining background QoS by seeing whether it runs in low power mode. Low power does not mean that something on a background QoS dispatch or operation queue _cannot run,_ only that it _may not_ run (until you leave low power mode). If you want to see what the QoS is, refer to the thread’s `qualityOfService` value.

Comment: @Rob, Not sure about your second statement, since the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH39 states the following:
IMPORTANT

Optimally, run your app at a QoS level of utility or lower at least 90% of the time when user activity is not occurring.

On iPhones, discretionary and background operations, including networking, are paused when Low Power Mode is enabled. See React to Low Power Mode on iPhones."

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk - Yes. I just tested it. (I really don't mean this to sound as snarky as I’m sure it will, but have you tested your claim?) Don’t get me wrong: I'm confident that the OS will curtail what sort of stuff will run on background/utility queues (I certainly hope it does!), but it would not appear to be as simple as “turn on low power mode and tasks dispatched to background queues can’t run.”

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk - FYI, [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1413553-qualityofservice) has been corrected to reflect that the operation's default value is `.default`, not `.background`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operation’s `qualityOfService` indicates whether the operation, itself, needs to dictate a particular QoS. But `-1`/`.default` effectively means that it will just use the QoS for the queue (and thus that of the worker thread that is used). I would not be terribly concerned about the QoS of the operation. What you care about is the QoS of the thread on which it runs:

```swift
let q = OperationQueue()
q.qualityOfService = .userInitiated

print("CURRENT", Thread.current.qualityOfService.rawValue)     // CURRENT 33
print("QUEUE", q.qualityOfService.rawValue)                    // QUEUE 25

let op = BlockOperation {
    print("THREAD", Thread.current.qualityOfService.rawValue)  // THREAD 25
}

q.addOperations([op], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

As you can see, the QoS for the thread that is running the code is precisely what you would expect it to be.

---

If you want, you can see how changing the operation’s QoS to something higher than the queue will affect the QoS of the worker thread upon which it runs. Thus, background QoS queue with no QoS specified for the operation:

```swift
let q = OperationQueue()
q.qualityOfService = .background

print("CURRENT", Thread.current.qualityOfService.rawValue)    // CURRENT 33
print("QUEUE", q.qualityOfService.rawValue)                   // QUEUE 9

let op = BlockOperation()
op.addExecutionBlock {
    print("OP", op.qualityOfService.rawValue)                 // OP -1
    print("THREAD", Thread.current.qualityOfService.rawValue) // THREAD 9
}

q.addOperations([op], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

But you can, if you want, specify a particular QoS for the operation, in this case escalating it to a higher QoS:

```swift
let q = OperationQueue()
q.qualityOfService = .background

print("CURRENT", Thread.current.qualityOfService.rawValue)    // CURRENT 33
print("QUEUE", q.qualityOfService.rawValue)                   // QUEUE 9

let op = BlockOperation()
op.qualityOfService = .userInitiated                          // change op’s QoS, and thus the worker thread to a higher QoS, too
op.addExecutionBlock {
    print("OP", op.qualityOfService.rawValue)                 // OP 25
    print("THREAD", Thread.current.qualityOfService.rawValue) // THREAD 25
}

q.addOperations([op], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

Comment: Thanks! On another note, would a `Process` inherit the current threads/ops QoS as well when invoked inside the OP? The `Process.qualityOfService` method is completely undocumented.

Comment: Try it and you will see that it does not inherit the thread/operation QoS, though if you explicitly set the QoS for the process, it does honor that.

Comment: So I should basically say `process.qualityOfService = Thread.current.qualityOfService` inside the op, just to be sure.

Comment: If you _really_ need the subprocess to have the same QoS as the operation, then, fine, do that. Two observations: First, most of the time, specifying the QoS doesn't matter too much and the default value is fine. Second, where it does matter, the current thread's QoS is probably less salient than the functional purpose and relative importance of the child process. But do whatever makes sense in your scenario. There's no hard and fast rule on this, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

There is [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH39) about the operation's inference of QoS from the queue (Section "**Quality of Service Inference and Promotion**").

The particular case of yours is described there as:

> Any of the queue’s operations with a lower QoS are promoted to the higher QoS.
> Any operations with a lower QoS that are added to the queue in the future will infer the higher QoS.

However, this does not mean that `op.qualityOfService` property is modified by the `OperationQueue`, because that would erase the QoS that you assigned to the operation. In other words, the value of the `op.qualityOfService` might not represent the promoted QoS, only the one that you assigned (or `.default`).

According to swift's [implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/931dd5f14ffc627b02cc240f23fc51d15ff95cf1/Sources/Foundation/Operation.swift#L488) of `Operation.swift`, the `op.queuePriority` is the property that represents the actual priority in the queue, after all the complicated logic of QoS inference and promotion is applied. You can map it back to QoS, same way as it's done forwards in the code I've just referred

Comment: Since an operation cannot do anything without a queue, and since the queue determines the effective qos of the operation, I wonder why an operation has a qos of its own at all.

Comment: They bias towards higher QoS - if the operation with QoS higher than the queue's one, is added into the queue, that operation will execute with its QoS, not with the queue's one.

Comment: Oh I see! OK, thanks for straightening that out.

Comment: But that higher QoS bias is true only at the moment of adding the operation. it's better to read the docs I referred to, since it's much more complicated when the queue that already has operations, is assigned with some QoS.

Comment: Yeah... still not getting it. This is way too complicated for what it is. I'll just manually pass the whole QoS setting through from `queue > operation > process/nstask` to make sure it is explicit.

Comment: @ErikAigner - Yeah, I’d suggest that one just sets the appropriate queue QoS, leave operations at `default` (i.e., don’t touch the operation’s QoS at all) and be done with it. IMHO, specifying operation-specific QoS just makes it harder to reason about one’s code. It’s complicated enough with dependencies, [`queuePriority`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1411204-queuepriority), etc., without adding another layer of QoS into the mix. If you have to override operation-specific QoS, fine, you can do that, but I have rarely found that useful.

Comment: @ErikAigner After reading this https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/931dd5f14ffc627b02cc240f23fc51d15ff95cf1/Sources/Foundation/Operation.swift#L488  I can suggest that `op.queuePriority` is the actual operation priority, and seems that's what you need. You can map it back to QoS, same way as its done forwards in the code I've just referred.